# Embedding record from function in OrientDB

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I'd like to embed a record into another one using a function in OrientDB.

I have a class called Backup. Here's it's definition:

```
create class Backup extends V
create property Backup.dateTime datetime
create property Backup.record embedded V
```

What I want to do is to call an OrientDB function, passing it an arbitrary @rid, and it will make a backup of that record for me.  Here's what I tried so far:

```
//function createBackup(id)

var gdb = orient.getGraphNoTx();

var rec = gdb.command("sql", "select from V where @rid = ?", [id]);

var v = gdb.command("sql", "create vertex Backup set dateTime = ?, record = ?", [(new Date().getTime()), rec[0].getRecord().toJSON()]);

...
```

Tried using `rec[0]`, or `rec[0].getRecord()` instead, but function always throws an error at me. Any ideas?

Comment: what error? it works :)

Comment: @vitorenesduarte, that doesnt work for me. ```rec[0].getRecord().toJSON()``` gives me ```Thefield'Backup.record'hasbeendeclaredasEMBEDDEDbutanincompatibletypeisused``` error. Then ```rec[0].getRecord()``` gives me ```Thefield'Backup.record'hasbeendeclaredasEMBEDDEDbutthevalueistheRecordID```. And finally ```rec[0]``` gives the same as the previous one. Which one worked for you? Which DB version are you using? Have you actually tried it with ```embedded``` datatype?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. I didn't try with `embedded`. But it's weird what you're trying to achieve. By definition, embedded documents don't own an RID, and the one you're trying to backup, owns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OrientDB - v2.0.6**

```
var graph = orient.getGraphNoTx();

var query = "select @this.exclude('@rid').toJson() as json from V where @rid = " + id;
var result = graph.command("sql", query);

var command = "create vertex Backup " 
            + "set dateTime = " + new Date().getTime() + ", "
            + "    record   = " + result[0].getRecord().field('json');    
graph.command("sql", command);

return;
```

Comment: That worked very well :) I guess parameterized queries arent the way to go next time