# OrientDB Timestamp on Update via a hook

Tags: orientdb

Does anyone have a working example of a hook to update a document with a timestamp on update?

I was able to set the timestamp on record creation by using `DEFAULT sysdate()`.

This doesn't help me when updating an existing record. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know this too. It isn't clear how to manipulate data with a hook from the docs. I've started another question on GG.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/s3Q5ZE8hFlU

One other thing I'd like to note. You probably would want to work with the datetime type and use `sysdate.toLong()` as the default. I think. :-)

Scott

Comment: I've also found this, which does what you want, but with Java. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/orientdb/orientdb_hooks.htm
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Ok. [Check out this thread in GG.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/s3Q5ZE8hFlU) I posted a Javascript function, which does what you are asking for.

All you need to do is save what I came up with as a custom function then create the customer trigger property on your class. [See this section of the docs on how to do that.](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Dynamic-Hooks.html)

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the first answer is great but [here's another option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663550/orientdb-automatic-on-record-changelog-via-trigger/35755405#35755405) I wrote for myself. It takes a schemaless prop from your updating record to save the editing user, and could be extended to save the field being updated too.